# plpgsql dynamically add select query to variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am attempting to loop through a varchar array with many schemas and dynamically construct a massive select statement. the 1st 2 raise notices work fine but I do not know how append the dynamic select statement into one large select.

Ideally I want something like this

```
SELECT 
    st_asmvtgeom(st_transform(t.geom,3857),b.geom) AS geom
    ,parcel_id
FROM schema1.parcel t 
JOIN bounds b
    ON st_intersects(t.geom,st_transform(b.geom,4269))
UNION
SELECT 
    st_asmvtgeom(st_transform(t.geom,3857),b.geom) AS geom
    ,parcel_id
FROM schema2.parcel t 
JOIN bounds b
    ON st_intersects(t.geom,st_transform(b.geom,4269))
```

the code

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   a varchar[] := array['schema1','schema2'];
   i integer; 
   slct varchar;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1 .. array_upper(a, 1)
   LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE '%', a[i]; 
      RAISE NOTICE 'SELECT st_asmvtgeom(st_transform(t.geom,3857),b.geom) AS geom,parcel_id
                      FROM %.parcel t join bounds b
                        on st_intersects(t.geom,st_transform(b.geom,4269))',a[i];
      EXECUTE 'SELECT st_asmvtgeom(st_transform(t.geom,3857),b.geom) AS geom,parcel_id
                      FROM %.parcel t join bounds b
                        on st_intersects(t.geom,st_transform(b.geom,4269))',a[i] into slct;         
   END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

the error

```
ERROR:  query "SELECT 'SELECT st_asmvtgeom(st_transform(t.geom,3857),b.geom) AS geom,parcel_id
                      FROM %.parcel t join bounds b
                        on st_intersects(t.geom,st_transform(b.geom,4269))',a[i]" returned 2 columns
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 17 at EXECUTE
SQL state: 42601
```

updated qry and error

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT st_asmvtgeom(st_transform(t.geom,3857),b.geom) AS geom,parcel_id
              FROM $1.parcel t join bounds b
                on st_intersects(t.geom,st_transform(b.geom,4269))' into slct 
                using a[i];
```

error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 2:        FROM $1.parcel t join bounds b
                    ^
QUERY:  SELECT st_asmvtgeom(st_transform(t.geom,3857),b.geom) AS geom,parcel_id
                      FROM $1.parcel t join bounds b
                        on st_intersects(t.geom,st_transform(b.geom,4269))
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 17 at EXECUTE
SQL state: 42601
```

Comment: Read the docs [Execute](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) and look at `format` example.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I did and adjusted accordingly but I have a new error

Comment: You did not use the `format` example as a guide:`EXECUTE format('UPDATE tbl SET %I = $1 WHERE key = $2', colname) USING newvalue, keyvalue;`. You can't use `$1` as a parameter for the schema name, you need to use `%I` and include the schema variable in the `format` function. For more information see [Format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)

Comment: You don't really need dynamic SQL for this. Just use a `set schema = ...` before running the query. You also can't return a result from an anonymous DO block. You will need to write a set returning function anyways.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this plans to be in a function -- the DO block was just easier to test for now

Comment: @AdrianKlaver ahh i see okay trying that now

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Im still having trouble what does the colname refer to in the docs, it doesnt say!

Comment: `%I`, the column name that the `SET` is referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the finite amount of schemas then you could to use the plain SQL like

```
SELECT ...
FROM schema1.parcel t 
JOIN bounds b
    ON st_intersects(t.geom,st_transform(b.geom,4269))
WHERE 'schema1' = any(array['schema1','schema2'])
UNION
SELECT ...
FROM schema2.parcel t 
JOIN bounds b
    ON st_intersects(t.geom,st_transform(b.geom,4269))
WHERE 'schema2' = any(array['schema1','schema2'])
UNION
SELECT ...
FROM schema3.parcel t 
JOIN bounds b
    ON st_intersects(t.geom,st_transform(b.geom,4269))
WHERE 'schema3' = any(array['schema1','schema2'])
```

If you want to build the query dinamically then you could to do that in single query:

```
select
    string_agg(format($$SELECT * FROM %I.parcel t 
JOIN bounds b
    ON st_intersects(t.geom,st_transform(b.geom,4269)
$$, shm), e'UNION\n') as sql
FROM unnest(array['schema1','schema2']) as shm;

┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                          sql                          │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ SELECT * FROM schema1.parcel t                       ↵│
│ JOIN bounds b                                        ↵│
│     ON st_intersects(t.geom,st_transform(b.geom,4269)↵│
│ UNION                                                ↵│
│ SELECT * FROM schema2.parcel t                       ↵│
│ JOIN bounds b                                        ↵│
│     ON st_intersects(t.geom,st_transform(b.geom,4269)↵│
│                                                       │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Use the result of this query as an argument of the `EXECUTE` statement.

Several notes.

You could to use dollar-quoted strings to keep syntax highlighting. Compare

```
select 'select
*
from foo';

select $$select
*
from foo$$;
```

Use `format()` function with `%I` placeholder for identifiers:

```
select format('%s %I', 'FooBar', 'FooBar');

┌─────────────────┐
│     format      │
├─────────────────┤
│ FooBar "FooBar" │
└─────────────────┘
```

Comment: the array is going to be 50 something items in it, my example was just a test. I'll see what your suggestions yeild

Comment: @ziggy So use the second case

Comment: your unnest query helped me solved it so I will accept your answer. I also found another way which I will add as an answer